# How do I remove a cloned GitHub repo from VSCode?

Tags: flutter, github

I created a new GitHub repository for my project (flutter project) but then I deleted it and now the cloned repo to the VSCode project in the Editor fails to get deleted/removed and now I’m having issues creating a new repo for the project. I’ll really appreciate some help to resolve this please.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Nobody here can read your mind, so please describe what you did. Also, what is the relevant relation to Flutter and VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the [Dark/Flutter plugins for VSCode](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode), you can try:

- create a new Flutter project in a folder
- close VSCode
- make sure the old one is gone from your disk
- reopen VSCode and see if you can go on working in the new project